# Search products by attributes from database in optimal way

Tags: php, mysql, search, entity-attribute-value

I want to find an effective way to search products by attributes from database, where data is organized by [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

There are 2 tables:

- Product, stores products, has product id.
- ProductAttribute - attribute values for products.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `Product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `ProductAttribute` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   # in real code it's attribute_id and value_id,
   # I just simplified this
  `attribute` varchar(10), 
  `value` varchar(255)
)
```

Different products can have different number of attributes. E. g. product 't-shirt' has size and color, whether product 'notebook' has cpu and ram. There can be more than 10 attributes for a product.

I want to create a search page for products, letting user select values from filters, appopriate for current product type.

My problem is that MySQL query for search from these tables would be inefficient. Search by 10 product attributes requires 10 JOINS with ProductAttribute table:

```
SELECT P.id
FROM Product P
JOIN ProductAttribute A1 ON (P.id = A1.product_id AND A1.attribute = 'cpu' AND A1.value = 'xxx')
JOIN ProductAttribute A2 ON (P.id = A2.product_id AND A2.attribute = 'ram' AND A2.value = 'yyy')
JOIN ProductAttribute A3 ON (P.id = A3.product_id AND A3.attribute = 'hdd' AND A3.value = 'zzz')
# ... more attributes require more joins
```

I can imagine how would I solve this: I could create index table(s) for each attibute set (one table for notebooks, another table for t-shirts and so on), and regenerate these index tables on product attributes change.

But I wonder if there is existing solution for this, maybe some search engine that can do this work.

I use PHP/MySQL, but I am not limited with this - any solution would be interesting.

**UPDATE**: (SPOILER: I still interested if any search engines/indexers exist for this task) I created comparison test for query with multiple JOINSs and query by index table. Index table is a table where all attributes are separate columns. Result: JOINS - 4.5s, index table - 0.2s. [See it on github](https://github.com/cronfy/mysql-search-test).

Example query with JOINs:

```
SELECT P.id FROM Product P
JOIN ProductAttribute color ON (P.id = color.product_id AND color.attribute_id = 17 AND color.int_value IN (152,146,101,152,118,109))
JOIN ProductAttribute size ON (P.id = size.product_id AND size.attribute_id = 34 AND size.int_value IN (288,210,246,275,258,289))
JOIN ProductAttribute brand ON (P.id = brand.product_id AND brand.attribute_id = 51 AND brand.int_value IN (305,303,300,375,308,340))
JOIN ProductAttribute material ON (P.id = material.product_id AND material.attribute_id = 68 AND material.int_value IN (426,463,465,459,418,460))
JOIN ProductAttribute length ON (P.id = length.product_id AND length.attribute_id = 85 AND length.float_value > 10 AND length.float_value < 49)
JOIN ProductAttribute height ON (P.id = height.product_id AND height.attribute_id = 102 AND height.float_value > 78 AND height.float_value < 186)
JOIN ProductAttribute weight ON (P.id = weight.product_id AND weight.attribute_id = 119 AND weight.float_value > 10 AND weight.float_value < 15)
JOIN ProductAttribute waterproof ON (P.id = waterproof.product_id AND waterproof.attribute_id = 136 AND waterproof.bool_value = 1)
JOIN ProductAttribute tags ON (P.id = tags.product_id AND tags.attribute_id = 153 AND tags.string_value LIKE '%alluring%')
;
```

Takes 4.5s to execute.

Example query by index table:

```
SELECT P.id FROM Product P
JOIN AttributeIndex AI ON (P.id = AI.product_id)
WHERE 
AI.color IN (152,146,101,152,118,109) 
AND AI.size IN (288,210,246,275,258,289) 
AND AI.brand IN (305,303,300,375,308,340) 
AND AI.material IN (426,463,465,459,418,460) 
AND AI.length > 10 AND AI.length < 49 
AND AI.height > 78 AND AI.height < 186 
AND AI.weight > 10 AND AI.weight < 15 
AND AI.waterproof = 1 
AND AI.tags LIKE '%alluring%';
```

Takes 0.2s to execute.

CREATE TABLE for tests (more information on [github](https://github.com/cronfy/mysql-search-test)):

```
CREATE TABLE `Product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `ProductAttribute` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `int_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `float_value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `bool_value` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `string_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `PA` (`product_id`,`attribute_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `AttributeIndex` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `material` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `waterproof` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `P` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

So, I can see that index tables are much more efficient than JOINs for this case. I would like to know if there is any solution that can help to generate (and keep in actual state) such index tables or provides some other way of fast search through products with multiple attributes.

Comment: Implementing search properly is very hard and you'd be reinventing many wheels along the way. If you can I'd suggest using something like [SOLR](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/), it's easy to use and will really pay off over the long term.

Comment: @Strawberry it requires multiple joins. For > 10k products it is slow.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, I added UPDATE info. Running tests now.

Comment: Are you still panning? on development? how many rows do you expect to handle on the attributes table? this will help to provide a better recommendation

Comment: @Strawberry About performance - I ran some tests on syntethic data of 10k products with 10 attributes. There is index on  (product_id,attribute_id). If `value` is integer, it is pretty fast. But in real life attributes can be `varchar`. If I change type to `varchar`, It takes about 0.3-0.4s to query Product Ids with LIKE search (10 JOINS) on short strings attribute values (I consider it slow). I can't run same query against real data, because it need to be transformed to follow structure described in the post, but I have strong feeling it will take tenths of seconds and more to query data.

Comment: @phobia82 I want to migrate database to the described structure, and then rewrite catalog search page, but I have feeling that 10 JOINS will make catalog search slow. So, currently I am planning it.

Comment: @Strawberry "even weirder is that no columns are selected from the OUTER TABLE" - I simplified the query, of course in real code SELECT will query more columns and attributes too.

Comment: Yes, but you're still using an INNER JOIN instead of an OUTER one. This makes a difference!

Comment: Yep. Takes me 0.31 secs too. I guess the difference is that I can live with that!

Comment: If I change the attribute data type to INT (retaining value as VARCHAR) then the execution time drops to 0.1s

Comment: I think a useful idea when employing an EAV model is to separate entities out according to value data type. So you'd have a table of date type values, a table of integer values, a table of decimal type things, and a table of varchar type things.

Comment: @Strawberry I ran some more tests with better data and more realistic queries and updated the question. Briefly: JOINs query is 20 times slower than query by index table. I am still wondering if there is a solution.

Comment: The slow bit here is the last line: ` AND tags.string_value LIKE '%alluring%';` - specifically the first percentage sign which means you cannot use an index.

Comment: @Strawberry if I remove `LIKE`, it is still takes 4.5s to execute.

Comment: It's great that you're now taking advantage of data types, but my earlier comment specifically suggested creating them as separate tables - so you didn't have thousands of null values - although I'm not sure what (if any) impact this has on performance.

Comment: Can you post the current CREATE TABLE statements in the question. My example had a UNIQUE index on (entity,attribute,value).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128738/discussion-between-cronfy-and-strawberry).